# Linked List Queue wipes out the entire chain after one call to dequeue()

Tags: c++, queue

I'm trying to make a program that runs a simulation. Using breakpoints I have verified that the enqueue method runs the correct number of times and there appears to be a full linked list of nodes. Then the program is supposed to run a dequeue method a certain number of times. The dequeue method runs once and for some reason it breaks the list right after the first node. Then when dequeue tries to call the getNext() function to get the next node, I receive the error "Access violation reading location." I can't figure out why it is doing this. Let me know if you need to see more code.  All help is appreciated.
Here is the Node.cpp.

```
Node::Node(Frame data) : data(data), next(NULL)
{}

Node::Node(Frame data, Node node) : data(data), next(&node)
{}

void Node::setData(Frame data){
    this->data = data;
}

Frame Node::getData(){
    return data;
}

void Node::setNext(Node node){
    this->next = &node;
}

Node Node::getNext(){
    return *next;
```

Queue methods

```
PPLQueue::PPLQueue() : length(0), firstNode(NULL), lastNode(NULL)
{}

bool PPLQueue::enqueue(Frame data, int maxSize){
Node *newNode = new Node(data);

if(isFull(maxSize))
    return false;
else if(isEmpty()){
    firstNode = newNode;
    lastNode = newNode;
    incrementLength();
}
else{
    lastNode->setNext(*newNode);
    lastNode = newNode;
    incrementLength();
}
return true;
}

Node* PPLQueue::dequeue(){
Node *nodeProbe = firstNode;

if(isEmpty())
    return nodeProbe;
else if(length > 1){
    *firstNode = nodeProbe->getNext();
    decrementLength();
    return nodeProbe;
}
else{
    firstNode = NULL;
    lastNode = NULL;
    decrementLength();
    return nodeProbe;
}
}

bool PPLQueue::isFull(int maxSize){
if(length == maxSize)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

bool PPLQueue::isEmpty(){
if(length == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

The code that calls the methods:

```
            for(int i=0; i < burstSize; i++){
            if(!queue.enqueue(frame, bucketSize)){
                discardedFrames += (burstSize - i);
                break;
            }
        }
        burstTime[burstCount] = time(NULL);
        burstCount++;
    }

    for(int j = 0 ; j < framesToRelease; j++){
        if(queue.dequeue() != NULL){
            releasedFrames++;
        }
```

When I get the error and the Access violation the program has stopped at the getNext method in the Node.cpp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems start here:

```
Node::Node(Frame data, Node node) : data(data), next(&node)
{}
```

and here:

```
void Node::setNext(Node node){
    this->next = &node;
}
```

where you store pointers to the arguments, whose lifetimes end when the function returns.
Dereferencing these pointers is undefined and can have unexpected results, such as not causing problems until much later.

They should look like this:

```
Node::Node(Frame data, Node* node) : data(data), next(node)
{}

void Node::setNext(Node* node){
    this->next = node;
}
```